# Swagger UI - Hide definition URL path

Tags: swagger-ui

Using `Swagger - UI` 3XX

I would like to simply know if this is possible and if so, how:

We currently have a need to `hide` the definition URL path that `Swagger - UI` displays.

[image]

I know it's not possible to remove this URL and I'm not looking to do that, all I'm wanting to do is to hide /mask the text box from the client viewing this page.

Looking at the new Swagger docs [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#parameters), there are some awesome tricks and extras you can add, however - nothing I can see in relation to my query.

I'm pretty sure, I could interrogate the HTML, find the id of the element in question and manually change the display of it within the index.html, I would much rather prefer using a build in method, if one exists before getting to that possible solution.

i.e. Something like this is possible and works:

```
<style> .download-url-input { display: none !important; } </style>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 28):

In Swagger UI 3.x, you can hide the top bar in one the following ways.

#### Option 1

Edit `dist\index.html` and find this code:

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  deepLinking: true,
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
    SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
  ],
  plugins: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
  ],
  layout: "StandaloneLayout"
})
```

Remove `layout`, `SwaggerUIStandalonePreset` and `SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl`, so that the constructor looks like this:

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
  deepLinking: true,
  presets: [
    SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
  ]
})
```

([Source](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3229#issuecomment-336556255))

#### Option 2 - Recompile Code

You can also recompile Swagger UI without the top bar plugin as explained [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#topbar-plugin) and rebuilding it. You will need Node.js 6.x and npm 3.x.

1. Edit `src/standalone/index.js` and remove TopbarPlugin from presets:

   ```js
   // import TopbarPlugin from "plugins/topbar"    // <----------
   import ConfigsPlugin from "plugins/configs"

   // the Standalone preset

   let preset = [
     // TopbarPlugin,      // <----------
     ConfigsPlugin,
     () => {
       return {
         components: { StandaloneLayout }
       }
     }
   ]
   ```
2. Rebuild Swagger UI – in the project's root directory run

   ```
   npm install
   ```

   then

   ```
   npm run build
   ```

Now your `dist\index.html` does not have a top bar.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was hoping there was a parameter that could have been used for this, but further research doesn't look like it. Also, this page (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3229) can help anyone else looking to do it, manually (using the TopBatPlugin).

Comment: @Hexie According to the latest comments in that thread, there's another approach that doesn't require recompilation. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, that will simply remove the css / html element that displays the header. I was hoping to mask / replace or hide the URL, all whilst leaving the css and style in place.

Comment: For option 1, if you're using a newer version of Swagger UI, edit `dist/swagger-initializer.js`.

Comment: What to do in docker? Ideally, there should be env parameter for that.

Comment: @quant2016 for a Docker solution see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3229#issuecomment-479106484

Answer (score 3):

For the version 3.x add slice function to:

```
SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.slice(1)
```

In the version 4.x (inside swagger-initializer.js file) set layout to  "BaseLayout"

```
  window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "./swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "BaseLayout" // <<< here
  });
```